# Open Camera + Image Show On Activity Is Not Working In My Xiaomi Phone

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

Hello I Am Running a Open Camera Code In My Phone. The Open Camera Code Is Working But Image is I Clicked Is not Show On Activity In Only My Redmi Phone.
My Activity is Show Blank Activity. Image Is Not Come Only In My Xiaomi Phone.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaosV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV9Dl.png)

Comment: Code is Working In Other Phone Fine.

Comment: what OS version does your phone run?

Comment: Android version  6.0 marshmallow

Comment: and Other MIUI 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your device runs on Marshmallow, try checking for runtime permissions once.

A good start can be found [here](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en)

And if you dont wish to modify your code but to test whether you code works or not, you can go to the app manager->permissions->-> here grant the `storage` permission. and then check if it works or not, if it works then you need to add permission requests for the same!

As per your code snippet you have added runtime permissions:

something like this:

```
final String permission = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                    if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        sendCameraIntent(requestCode);
                    } else {
                        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission)) {
                .......
```

where `sendCameraIntent()` is the method which sends the intent, also you have added the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE` which is not needed as such. just `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` works too!

Comment: permission is given but one app is working and another is not working . problem is that open camera + image is captured but not come on my activity.

Comment: can you add your image request intent code to your main post

Comment: please check edit. Not run time permissions are added!

Comment: before you create a new file